# Declare a variable or function in one library and define it in another

Tags: objective-c, c, frameworks, forward-declaration

I have a library I use in all my apps, containing common code.  I compile it as a "Framework" for Mac and a "Static Library" for iOS.

**I would like for the library to be able to reference a variable which is defined by the final including project.**

For example, the library has a function:

```
void printAppID(void);

void printAppID(void) {
    NSLog(@"App ID is: %@", kAppID);
}
```

Naturally, the library will throw warnings if this variable is not declared, so I have declared it as:

```
NSString *kAppID;
```

And since `kAppID`  is not known to the library in advance (it is different for every project), the final project does something like:

```
NSString *kAppID = @"ABCD1234"
```

This throws a compiler error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture

I have tried using `extern`, or making it a function, or a `#define`, and can't crack this one.

What is the canonical way of **declaring a variable in a library and defining it somewhere else**?  I'm thinking this is the same in C as it in in Obj-C.

### EDIT: more generalized case

**How can I have a compiled static library that is included in an app project together with a Constants.h header file, whose values can be edited in that project and be used by the library?**

Answer (score 2):

The cannonical way is probably to have somewhere a `setAppID` method in the library, that must be called by the app to set the ID.

That is, the `kAppID` is part of the library:

```
static NSString* kAppID = nil;

void setAppID (NSString* appID) {
    kAppID = appID;
}

// ...library can use kAppID as necessary...
```

Comment: This is what I'm using now and it works.  Unfortunately it still requires the consumer of the library to do some "programming" instead of just changing a text value, so I'm not sure I really should mark this as the correct answer.  Unless what I'm trying to do simply *cannot* be done.

Comment: I'm glad it works! Though I'm not sure why it's an issue if the user of the library has to do some programming - surely they have to do so anyway in order to actually use your library? This way only requires one extra function call, and is no more work than adding an extra variable would be. Besides, it increases encapsulation - which is generally considered to be a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

extern is the correct way.

in your lib:

```
extern NSString* const kAppID;
```

somewhere in your project:

```
NSString* const kAppID = @"ABCD1234";
```

using a Singleton Object in your lib you can configurate from you project is propably a better way. But if you want the linker to crash if something is not set, using extern is the right way to do so.

Comment: Sorry, this does not compile.  Same error.  I like your other suggestion but that requires subclassing or having some other kind of in-code routine, which is awkward for sharing a library (even with myself).

Comment: @SG1 if you get an undefined symbol you are doing something wrong linking the libary or so. `extern` will definitely work. You HAVE TO define your symbol inside your project.

Comment: Jonathan, you might be right about having to define the symbol - that seems to be the problem.  But if you look again at the question, you will see that by very nature of the problem the symbol is declared in the library project but it is not defined until the app project which uses a compiled version of the library - if I could get it to compile, that is.

Comment: @JonathanCichon I have given you +1 cause this is the way I do it, but I have been told this is bad many a time by different developers including ones on here could you explain why this would be bad if you know?